# Why does Java HashMap treeify() compare hash values of nodes in the same bucket?

Tags: java, hashmap, red-black-tree

I'm currently studying the internals of the HashMap implementation in Java. I noticed something that I can't quite wrap my head around in the treeify() method.
Here's the portion of the treeify() method that I'm referring to:

```
if ((ph = p.hash) > h)
    dir = -1;
else if (ph < h)
    dir = 1;
```

My understanding is that items within the same bucket in a HashMap tend to have the same internal hash code as this is what was used to assign them to that bucket in the first place. If that's the case, then these lines of code which compare the internal hash codes of nodes within the same bucket would never evaluate to true.

So my question is: Why does treeify() need to compare these hash codes? Are there any scenarios where items in the same bucket can have different internal hash codes? In other words, are there any situations where the above condition can be true? If not, wouldn't comparing internal hash codes be unnecessary?

In the end, treeify() method primarily uses Comparable interface and tieBreakOrder() method for sorting the items within the tree, so it seems strange to have lines of code for comparing what appear to be identical hash values.
Any insights into this would greatly be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: >Are there any scenarios where items in the same bucket can have different internal hash codes? Yes, maybe after `resize()/replacementTreeNode(...)` (treeifyBin) or after `untreeify()` (split) ... https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L2071

Comment: @xerx593 I initially thought that the hash values would also change during the resize() process, as the hashing algorithm might be altered based on the new size to redistribute the entries. However, upon closer inspection, it seems that resize() only reallocates buckets and does not modify the hash values of nodes. Therefore, the assumption that items in the same bucket can have different hash values seems plausible. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: See my answer. In a typical hashmap the number of buckets (some power of 2, by default starting at 16) is small compared to the number of possible hashcodes (the whole range of `int` values, i.e. 4 billion values). Several hashcodes are therefore mapped to the same bucket number which in turn means that a single bucket can contain keys with different hashcodes.

Answer (score 1):

The bucket is selected using not using the hashcode (*) itself but using the hashcode modulo number of buckets. For example in `putVal()` the bucket number `i` is calculated as `(n - 1) & hash`:

> ```
>     if ((p = tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]) == null)
>        tab[i] = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
> ```

For the default starting number of buckets of 16 keys with hashcodes of 0, 16, 32, and so on all end up in the same bucket 0.

Since treeifying starts when there are many entries in the same bucket and those entries can have different hashcodes it makes sense to build the tree by sorting by hashcode first before starting to compare (which may take longer, for example for long strings).

---

*) Actually it doesn't use the result of calling `key.hashCode()` directly, it uses the following function:

> ```
>  static final int hash(Object key) {
>     int h;
>     return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
> }
> ```

In this function for a non-null key `h` is assigned the keys hashcode and then the upper 16 bits are xored into the lower 16 bits which modifies the lower 16 bits of the result but leaves the upper 16 bits intact.

Thus the values of `hash` in the first code snippet contains still 2^32 distinct values, which is still larger then the size of the bucket array which still means that more than one hashcode value maps to the same bucket.

Comment: I think the hash in the signature of the putVal method does not use the actual hashcode of the object. When examining the put method, it calls hash(key) before calling putVal, which, to my understanding, applies the HashMap's internal hashing function and uses this to determine the bucket index for storage. I understand that each node stores the key, value, and the hashcode processed by this internal function. Therefore, the explanation that different hashcodes can end up in the same bucket as in your example is still not clear to me. Could there be any misunderstandings on my part?

Comment: @yong_ta_Park did you have a look at the `hash()` method, especially its JavaDoc? This does not apply "the HashMap's internal hashing function" but rather uses the key's hash code and adjusts it to reduce the chance of collisions. So yes, the internally stored hash code is not exactly what `key.hashcode()` would return but it's based on it.

Comment: @yong_ta_Park In general, even if hashmap would calculate completely different hash codes (in which case the key's `hashcode()` method would be useless) the explanation still holds: the hash code values will likely be larger than the number of buckets and thus the modulo operator is applied to select the bucket. Compare it to how tax offices work in some countries: they distribute tax payers to their employees by family name, e.g. employee 1 gets A-F, employee 2 gets G-M, etc. - Internally those employees might then sort their "bucket" again by family name or some other criteria.

Comment: You might want to research the spate of 2011 hashtable denial of service attacks to find out why "treeify" is there at all.

Comment: @Thomas 
Thank you for the kind explanation.

I am currently trying to understand HashMaps by looking at the JavaDoc. I am understanding the storage process in HashMaps like this - when storing an element, it uses the key's object.hashcode() to generate a unique hash value, which is then processed by the internal hash() function of the HashMap. This returned value is assigned as the hash value of the Node, and this hash value is used to determine the bucket index value, where it is then stored.

Comment: @Thomas
I am understanding hash collisions as instances where the calculated bucket index values, despite being different elements, end up being stored in the same bucket index. I assumed that 'all elements in one bucket have the same hash() value.'

Therefore, I was confused when looking at the treeify method. My assumption was that 'all elements in a bucket are guaranteed to have the same hash() value.'

Comment: However, after reading @xerx593's comment and examining the resize() method, I saw that while resize() does redistribute the existing buckets, it does not modify the Node's hash value. So now, I am assuming that 'there can be cases where the conditions for comparing hash values in treeify are true. This is because methods like resize(), while reallocating certain elements to different buckets, do not change the hash value, meaning different hash values can exist within the same bucket.' Is my assumption correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Additionally, I regret that I may not fully understand the answers you provide due to my limited knowledge, and I am grateful for your kind and additional explanations.

Comment: @yong_ta_Park yes, you're right. The hash value of a key doesn't change so a bucket may contain elements with different hash codes - in fact all or at least elements should have different hash codes. The assignment to the same bucket is the basic reason why `equals()` needs to be implemented along with `hashCode()` (see JavaDoc). Also, a good hashing algorithm would generate more or less evenly distributed unique hashes but finding those can very hard so you'll normally find some approximations with "good enough" distribution for most cases.